# Cannot generate LaTeX from Javadoc

Tags: latex, javadoc

I've been getting this kind of error

> javadoc: error - Cannot find doclet class 'org.stfm.textdoclet.TeXDoclet'

I downloaded the TexDoclet.jar from http://doclet.github.com/ and followed the instructions

```
javadoc -doclet 'org.stfm.txtdoclet.TeXDoclet' -docletPath 'C:\Users\Kaede\Desktop\TeXDoclet.jar'
```

But it keeps throwing the error class not found.
I've checked the jar and the TeXDoclet.class was inside the `org.stfm.textdoclet`.

What can be the problem causing this error?

Comment: have you added TexDoclet.jar in classpath ?

Comment: No.. its not part of the instruction to add it to classpath.. should I add it?

Comment: yes please , as the error you are getting is "Cannot find doclet class 'org.stfm.textdoclet.TeXDoclet'" , so please add and then run javadoc

Comment: hello, i've added the TexDoclet.jar in the classpath, but the error still occurs...

Comment: can you paste your classpath value please

Comment: C:\Users\Kaede\Desktop\TeXDoclet.jar

Comment: oh oh that should not be the correct value of classpath , I am sure you can change it via CONTROL PANEL -> SYSTEM -> ENVIRONMENT VARIABlES , all you have to do is to go there and add C:\Users\Kaede\Desktop\TeXDoclet.jar  at the end of classpath value

Comment: let me try downloading the file and see if I can make it work

Answer (score 0):

this is what I tried `javadoc -docletpath TeXDoclet.jar     -doclet org.stfm.texdoclet.TeXDoclet     -sourcepath src -subpackages com:data:structures -noindex -tree  -hyperref -output out.tex -title "My Title" -author "My Name"` , and it worked for me :)